# Want to assign dedicated default gateway on Two NIC card on linux server

Tags: networking, rhel

We have one server having two nic cards. Here we configured two separate networks on both nics and having different gateway. However our one sub-net is able to communicate to outside network second one not able to communicate with outside network.

Comment: are you able to connect to the gateway of that network? Please provide such inputs.

Comment: Yes we are able to ping both gateways however we are unable to ping second subnet from other network.

Comment: By outside network what do you mean? And how did you check the connection? What is the output you got? Please update your question with such information, only then other users will be able to help you out.